# Javascript Sort array order based on another array order using underscore

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

Basically my question in title. I got two arrays of objects.

**Array 1:**

```
var firstArray = [
{id: "1", value: 1},
{id: "5", value: 0.5},
{id: "3", value: 0.25},
{id: "4", value: 0.125},
{id: "2", value: 0.0625}
];
```

**Array 2:**

```
var secondArray = [
{id: 1, name: "a"},
{id: 2, name: "b"},
{id: 3, name: "c"},
{id: 4, name: "d"},
{id: 5, name: "e"}
];
```

How can I sort my second array so that order will match first array order like this:

**Result:**

```
var secondArray = [
{id: 1, name: "a"},
{id: 5, name: "e"},
{id: 3, name: "c"},
{id: 4, name: "d"},
{id: 2, name: "b"}
];
```

Comment: You have a more important question to answer: what are you going to do once you sort the second array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving an Underscore/Lodash answer since that's what the question title indicates the OP is after.  This code sorts the second array by the indexes of the corresponding id in the first array.

```js
$(function() {
    var firstArray = [
 {id: "1", value: 1},
 {id: "5", value: 0.5},
 {id: "3", value: 0.25},
 {id: "4", value: 0.125},
 {id: "2", value: 0.0625}
    ];
    var secondArray = [
 {id: 1, name: "a"},
 {id: 2, name: "b"},
 {id: 3, name: "c"},
 {id: 4, name: "d"},
 {id: 5, name: "e"}
    ];

    var sorted = _.sortBy(secondArray, function(obj) {
 return _.findIndex(firstArray, {id: obj.id.toString()});
    });

    console.log(sorted);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: returns same array, not sorted :(

Answer (score 2):

With plain ES6, you could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the index of the given `id` and sort it with the index of `firstArray`.

A problem is the different type of `id` in the given arrays.

```js
var firstArray = [{ id: "1", value: 1 }, { id: "5", value: 0.5 }, { id: "3", value: 0.25 }, { id: "4", value: 0.125 }, { id: "2", value: 0.0625 }],
    secondArray = [{ id: 1, name: "a" }, { id: 2, name: "b" }, { id: 3, name: "c" }, { id: 4, name: "d" }, { id: 5, name: "e" }],
    map = new Map(firstArray.map(({ id }, i) => [+id, i]));

secondArray.sort((a, b) => map.get(a.id) - map.get(b.id));

console.log(secondArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

**[XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)**

I sense you have plans to relate the two arrays by index after the second array is sorted. I suggest an alternative means of relation

```js
const firstArray =
  [ {id: "1", value: 1}
  , {id: "5", value: 0.5}
  , {id: "3", value: 0.25}
  , {id: "4", value: 0.125}
  , {id: "2", value: 0.0625}
  ]

const secondArray =
  [ {id: 1, name: "a"}
  , {id: 2, name: "b"}
  , {id: 3, name: "c"}
  , {id: 4, name: "d"}
  , {id: 5, name: "e"}
  ]

const thirdArray =
  firstArray.map (x =>
    Object.assign (x, secondArray.find (y => y.id == x.id)))
    
console.log (thirdArray)
// [ { id: 1, value: 1, name: 'a' }
// , { id: 5, value: 0.5, name: 'e' }
// , { id: 3, value: 0.25, name: 'c' }
// , { id: 4, value: 0.125, name: 'd' }
// , { id: 2, value: 0.0625, name: 'b' } 
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Noting some casting (one array's `id` is a String, one is a Number), you can do this with ES6 [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (different from Nina's `Map`) and [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var firstArray = [
  {id: "1", value: 1},
  {id: "5", value: 0.5},
  {id: "3", value: 0.25},
  {id: "4", value: 0.125},
  {id: "2", value: 0.0625}
];

var secondArray = [
  {id: 1, name: "a"},
  {id: 2, name: "b"},
  {id: 3, name: "c"},
  {id: 4, name: "d"},
  {id: 5, name: "e"}
];

var result = firstArray.map(item => {
  return {
    id: Number(item.id),
    name: secondArray.find(element => element.id == item.id).name
  }
})

console.log(result)
```